# Multiple CircleCI machines/builds (nodejs + java/gradle)

Tags: node.js, gradle, circleci

I have a java application built with Gradle on CircleCI.

I need to be able to build and test a nodejs client module before it is packaged as a jar bundled with the main java app.

The client module is located within a sub-directory i.e. `/myapp-client`.

Here are roughly the steps I currently have in my bash shell:

- Changes directory into the sub-directory and downloads the npm dependencies:

`cd ./myapp-client && npm install`

- Changes directory and test the module:

`cd ./myapp-client && node_modules/.bin/ng test`

- Changes directory and builds the module:

`cd ./myapp-client && node_modules/.bin/ng build -prod`

Can you please provide guidelines as to how to achieve that with CircleCI?

Can I have a CircleCI machine/build based upon **both java and nodejs**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of those commands you've mentioned you can run from `circle.yml`: https://circleci.com/docs/configuration/

A build on CircleCI happens within a container. Both Java, NodeJS, and other languages are already pre-installed for your use.

Depending on your needs, you can also build the client module as a separate project.

Comment: Can you please provide pointers about how to build the client module as a separate project? Can I have two machine override within my `circle.yml`?

Comment: Having the client module as a separate project would mean having it in its own repo on GitHub or Bitbucket.

To keep things somewhat similar to your current setup, you can use a Git submodule in its place.